# How to get Spec file logs withoug using ActorLogging

Tags: scala, akka, spray, specs2, specs

I have test file like this

```
class SomeSpec extends Specification with Specs2RouteTest with SomeService
```

where I have written test cases, its workiing fine.

But I am not able to get log messages in log file, so I need to have logging in that spec, now we can do this by using

```
class SomeSpec extends Specification with Specs2RouteTest with 
SomeService with ActorLogging with Actor
```

my problem is I dont want to use `akka.actor.ActorLogging` without using it, I want to get logs of specss in log file, so can you suggest some other way for it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a non-Akaa logging library like [Scala Logging](https://github.com/typesafehub/scala-logging).

It provides several mixins so you can do something like:

```
class SomeSpec extends Specification with Specs2RouteTest with SomeService with LazyLogging {
  logger.debug("This is very convenient ;-)")
}
```